# Excel choosing x lowest values from 10000 records

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have 10000 numbers in column A (`A1:A10000`)

I want to fill column B with for example 90 lowest numbers from column A.

Maybe data analysis toolpack will help? But i don't know how...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
=SMALL($A$1:$A$10000,ROW(A1))
```

Put this in B1 and then drag it down 90 rows.

If you want the top 90:

```
=LARGE($A$1:$A$10000,ROW(A1))
```

Comment: Nice touch with the ROW() function. I can think of a lot of places where that could be useful.